# How to get the company ID of the Logged in user from a related table

Tags: laravel

I am trying to get the logged in user's `company_id`, In my Laravel 8 Job Portal application. I have these models:

- Department
- User
- Company
- CompanyProfile

A `User` can only appear once on the `users` table with unique `email`. But he can have more than one `CompanyProfile`, since he can work remotely for more than one `Company`:

These are the models:

```php
class Department extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'departments';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'company_id',
        'name',
    ];

    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Company','company_id');
    }
}

class Company extends Model
{    
    protected $table = 'companies';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'name',
        'org_image',
    ];

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\User');
    }

    public function departments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Department');
    }
}


class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 
        'first_name',
        'other_name',
        'last_name',
        'username',
        'email', 
        'password', 
    ];

    public function profile(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\CompanyProfile', 'employee_id');
    }

    public function company(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\CompanyProfile', 'company_id');
    }
}

class CompanyProfile extends Model
{    
    protected $table = 'company_profiles';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'user_id',
        'company_id',
        'department_id',
        'employment_date',
    ];
}
```

Having in mind that the `company_id` is not in the `User` model, How do I get the `company_id` of the Logged in `User` in the `DepartmentController`?

```php
public function index()
{           
    $departments = Department::where('company_id', ...)->get();
    return view('departments.index')->with('departments', $departments);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Basically, if I have this kind of scenario I will pass the company_id to the index method or you have to call the user's model with the relation to company then you got the company_id its just scenario

Comment: @RushikeshGanesh - Can you show me a samply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, you can use "hasManyThrough" relationship

change company relationship in user model as below

```
public function company(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\Company', 'App\Models\CompanyProfile');
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this but as per scenario i will do it like this

```
 public function index()
    {    
          $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
          $users_data = User::where('id',$user_id)->with('company')->first();
          $company_id = $users_data->company->company_id;
          $departments = Department::where('company_id', $company_id)->get();
          return view('departments.index')->with('departments', $departments);
    }
```